# How to import store to the Api layer? Got Webpack error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex

I am trying to import store to my api layer but i get this ‘TypeError: store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_.default is undefined’ error.

This is my Api.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../store';
import router from '../router';


const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.DEVELOPMENT_URL + process.env.VERSION,
  withCredentials: false,
  crossDomain: false,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'LanguageCode': 'EN',
    'CurrencyCode': 'DKK',
    'CompanyId': store.state.selectedCompany ? store.state.selectedCompany.CompanyId : '',
    'UserId': store.state.user.userID ||'',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  function(config) {
    const token = store.state.auth.token ? store.state.auth.token : '';

    if(token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },

  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

api.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response;
  },

  function(error) {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if(error.response.statusCode === 401 && originalRequest.url.includes("/authentication/login")) {

      router.push('/login');
    } else if(error.response.statusCode == 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      //refreshToken function will be here

      return axios(originalRequest);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);


export default api;
```

and this is the store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';


Vue.use(Vuex);

//Modules
import AuthModule from "../AuthModule/store/auth";


export default new Vuex.Store({
  
  modules: {
    
    ProductModule, 
    CreditorsModule,
    InvoicesModule,
    DebtorsModule,
    AuthModule,
    ModalsModule,
    MetadataModule,
  },
  state: {
    locked: false,
  },


});
```

I just couldn’t find out the mistake i made…

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I saw and responded to this question on the Vue Help Forum a bit ago, so I will add it here as well.

Obviously missing some other code here. Where are you creating your Vue instance? And are you including your store object in your Vue instance options?

Here is an example ‘main.js’ from one of my Vue 2 (Vue CLI) apps:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

If using Vue CLI and Single File Components, you can then access the store from any component with ‘this.$store’.